# my stopwords list is loaded but not working

Tags: mysql, stop-words

I have a modified stopwords list file, which basically took out the word 'alone'.  I have updated my `/etc/my.cnf`

```
ft_stopword_file=/etc/new_stopwords_list.txt
```

After restarting my mysql server, I did the following to show that mysql is indeed picking up the new variable.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft_stop%'

+------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                       |
+------------------+-----------------------------+
| ft_stopword_file | /etc/new_stopwords_list.txt |
+------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Afterward, I did a REPAIR TABLE to update the index.  However, when I do a search, the new setting does not seem to take effect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What mode are you using?. It could be because of the 50% threshold. Did you you check in this direction.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html